# Is it possible to give a application ADMINSTRATIVE rights to run properly but under a STANDARD user account?

Tags: active-directory

I have some applications that REQUIRE ADMINISTRATIVE RIGHTS in order to run properly.  But these programs are to be used by STANDARD users without ADMIN rights.  Do I have to set something up in the Group Policy to do this?  Or use Properties, Compatibility, "Run this program as an administrator"?  Either way, by giving admin rights to the software, would that standard rights user be able to do things as if an admin via that application that was given admin rights to function properly?

thank you!

Comment: Your best bet is to find out what additional access the application needs with a program like Process Monitor.  You may be able to grant just that right to the users instead of making them full administrators.  I've had a couple programs that just needed rights to a couple registry keys and then they would run as standard users.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 pro, server 2012 r2 essentials

Answer (score 3):

There's a [third party product](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBrokerforWindows/) (maybe more than one) that does this.  I used it at a previous employer.  You would have to whitelist the application, but yes, the whitelisted software that requires admin rights works fine when run by regular users.

If you don't want to use or can't afford a third party tool, you'll need to do what E-Rock suggested:  spend some time figuring out what files/registry keys/etc. you need to grant in order to run the program properly.  I can't guarantee it'll work, but sometimes it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can [set up a scheduled task](https://superuser.com/a/935587/1304) that will run the application with a specific user account and with administrative rights. You can then give your standard users the ability to start the scheduled task, and provide a shortcut that will start the task.